# convert php array to json format in symfony

Tags: php, json, symfony

I have this Json(see below) and I am trying actually to find a way to generate one like this using a php array. My question is how can I generate a json like this from a php array. in another way, I still don't know how to build that php array so that I can convert it to this a json like the one below. I am using symfony2 to render this a json like this one

```
var presentation = [{
                    "image": "images/cover.jpg",
                    "sentence": "This is a sentence",
                    "audio": "hello.mp3",
                    "sentence_info": [
                        {"start": 0, "end": 0.5 },
                        { "start": 0.5, "end": 1.2 }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "image": "images/cat.jpg",
                    "sentence": "This is another sentence",
                    "audio": "bey.mp3",
                    "sentence_info": [
                        { "start": 0, "end": 0.2 },
                        { "start": 0.2, "end": 0.8 },
                        { "start": 0.8, "end": 1.2 },
                        { "start": 1.2, "end": 1.5 },
                        { "start": 1.5, "end": 2 }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "image": "images/dog.jpg",
                    "sentence": "This is a third sentence",
                    "audio": "good.mp3",
                    "sentence_info": [
                        { "start": 0, "end": 0.5 },
                        { "start": 0.5, "end": 1.2 }
                    ]
                }
];
```

Comment: In your controller

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

and when you want to return JSON: return new JsonResponse(array('test'=>'test')); OR return new JsonResponse($yourarray);

Comment: thank, I actually get a quit gook result when I use JsonRespone(), but I get some weird extra characters in my array. this is what I get as a value in that array: "image":"\/ara\/web\/uploads\/images\/slide\/34.jpeg". the bad thing is that when I rey to pass that result to a javascript variable I get even a worst one: &quot;books&quot;:[{&quot;image&quot;:&quot;\/ara\/web\/uploads\/images\/slide\/32.jpeg&quot;

Comment: Your question is on hold... i can't correctly help you until this question is not re opened. Because i can't post in comment with formated code.

Comment: thanks, but I have already solved the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just simple array assignment in PHP. Like this:

```
public function whatEver()
{
    $presentation = array(
        array(
            'image' => 'images/cover.jpg',
            'sentence' => 'This is a sentence',
            'audio' => 'hello.mp3',
            'sentence_info' => array(
                array('start' => 0, 'end' => 0.5),
                array('start' => 0.5, 'end' => 1.2),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'image' => 'images/cat.jpg',
            'sentence' => 'This is another sentence',
            'audio' => 'bey.mp3',
            'sentence_info' => array(
                array('start' => 0, 'end' => 0.2),
                array('start' => 0.2, 'end' => 0.8),
                array('start' => 0.8, 'end' => 1.2),
                array('start' => 1.2, 'end' => 1.5),
                array('start' => 1.5, 'end' => 2),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'image' => 'images/dog.jpg',
            'sentence' => 'This is a third sentence',
            'audio' => 'good.mp3',
            'sentence_info' => array(
                array('start' => 0, 'end' => 0.5),
                array('start' => 0.5, 'end' => 1.2),
            ),
        ),
    );

    $presentation =  json_encode($presentation, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

    $response = new Response($presentation);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple look at the supplied json would should you that it is an array **`[]`** with various objects **`{}`** inside.

You'd be looping through data from wherever you get it from (*most likely a database?*) and then adding it to the array like this:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($data_from_wherever as $item) {
    $i = array(
        'image' => '',
        'sentence' => '',
        'audio' => '',
        'sentence_info' => array(
            array(
                'start' => '',
                'finish' => ''
            ),
            array(
                'start' => '',
                'finish' => ''
            ),
        // ......etcetc
        ),
    );

    array_push($data, $i);
}
```

Giving you an array that you'd [**`json_encode()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to acheive your desired output.

```
$presentation = json_encode($data);
```

---

And if you don't know how to get said data yet, you can simply create the `$data` array like below and then encode it.

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'image' => 'images/cover.jpg',
        'sentence' => 'This is a sentence',
        'audio' => 'hello.mp3',
        'sentence_info' => array(
            array('start' => 0, 'end' => 0.5),
            array('start' => 0.5, 'end' => 1.2),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'image' => 'images/cat.jpg',
        'sentence' => 'This is another sentence',
        'audio' => 'bey.mp3',
        'sentence_info' => array(
            array('start' => 0, 'end' => 0.2),
            array('start' => 0.2, 'end' => 0.8),
            array('start' => 0.8, 'end' => 1.2),
            array('start' => 1.2, 'end' => 1.5),
            array('start' => 1.5, 'end' => 2),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'image' => 'images/dog.jpg',
        'sentence' => 'This is a third sentence',
        'audio' => 'good.mp3',
        'sentence_info' => array(
            array('start' => 0, 'end' => 0.5),
            array('start' => 0.5, 'end' => 1.2),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: I have ended up trying another approach yesterday, and it it is working. but I am facing another problem related to do the the framework symfony2 this time.

Answer (score 1):

You would use [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on an array you've built up.

Comment: the problem is I still don't know how to build a phparray that will give me that result(json result) when i use json_encode

Comment: Assign $presentation in php that is a string, with the contents being everything inside of the JavaScript variable, wrapped in single quotes. Then var_dump(json_decode($presentation));